Happy Go Lucky - what was this in Chinese?
This sounds very much like certain well-known Pidgin English phrases of Chinese origin such as Look-See or No-Can-Do, but I'm struggling to think what it could have originally been in Chinese.
Is Happy-Go-Lucky a Chinese Pidgin English phrase, and if so what was the original phrase in Chinese?

According to the Oxford Dictionary - The earliest known use of the word happy-go-lucky is in the late 1600s. OED's earliest evidence for happy-go-lucky is from 1672, in the writing of William Wycherley, playwright. happy-go-lucky is formed within English, by compounding. Etymons: happy adj., go v., lucky adj. https://www.oed.com/dictionary/happy-go-lucky_adv?tl=true#:~:text=The%20earliest%20known%20use%20of,go%20v.%2C%20lucky%20adj.
And, according to the Cambridge Dictionary, in English, "happy-go-lucky" means "A happy-go-lucky person does not plan much and accepts what happens without becoming worried. Synonyms. carefree (無憂無慮). https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/happy-go-lucky

Not of Chinese origin, then.

Not to my knowledge. Famous Chinese-English phrases/slang are usually formed by word-by-word substitution, such as "people mountain people sea (人山人海)"; "long time no see ( 好久不見了). The direct substitution for "happy-go-lucky" would be "快樂走/去幸福/運", which makes no sense.

I normally use the idiom 萧摇自在, Xiāo Yáo Zì Zài, meaning: unfettered, unrestrained, at ease.
It comes from 白居易, Bái Jūyì, of the Tang Dynasty, titled, "View from Above the Bodhi Temple", 菩提寺上方远眺, "Pú tí sì shàng fāng yuǎn tiào"

I think 逍遙自在 is more in line with "duty-free - 無官一身輕".

I'm picturing a shop in Shanghai Airport named 逍遙自在 and offering reduced prices on wines and spirits...

I am not sure whether you are joking, but, "Duty-free" as interpreted by @r13 is not in the sense of "Custom-tax-free" He meant the sense that one has no "worries", "responsibilities", "duties", "burdens", and thus "free-and-easy", which means a person could also be "Happy-go-Lucky", because 逍遙 means "carefree", and 自在 means, amongst other definitions, "unrestrained", "unhindered" by any immediate "worries", "duties", like mundane, everyday work.

I think 隨遇而安 fits best, although the "happy" part is missing.
Maybe 樂天知命

Google Translate results for "Happy Go Lucky" is 無憂無慮 (carefree) is quite fitting.
Happy Go Lucky is also similar to a few Chinese expressions:
隨遇而安 - take things as they come (be content no matter what you encounter)
遊戲人間 - live life like it is a game (not take anything seriously)
聽天由命 - let gods and fate decide everything (resign yourself to fate)
